# komascript scrlttr2: how to put recipient's address on the right

Tags: scrlttr2

I need to put the recipient's address on the right of the letter.

I'm using `scrlttr2` class and I know that it is very flexible, but I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is that the standard in your country? If so, you should tell us the location and provide links to some official resources. Then we can provide stuff that is easily accesible by everyone in your country.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The horizontal position of the the address field is determined by the pseudolength `toaddrhpos`. A value of `toaddrhpos` greater than 0 means the distance from the left border, a value lower than 0 means the distance from the right border.

So you could use something like

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{-1cm}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength[-]{toaddrhpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%%% only to show the fields, do not use in your real document
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address,head}
%%%
\makeatletter
\@setplength[-]{toaddrhpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstr.12\\12345 Musterhausen}
\opening{Hello}
\blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Other pseudolengths related to the address field are `toaddrvpos`, `toaddrwidth` and `toaddrheight`.

And you can use `\addtokomafont{addressee}{\raggedleft}` to right align the address in the address field:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[backaddress=false,fromalign=right]{scrlttr2}
%%% only to show the fields, do not use in your real document
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address,head}
%%%
\makeatletter
\@setplength[-]{toaddrhpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\makeatother
\addtokomafont{addressee}{\raggedleft}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Kombi Karle}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Kaiserstr.\\Karlsruhe}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstr.12\\12345 Musterhausen}
\opening{Hello}
\blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

But there are also some Letter Class Option files included in the KOMA-Script Distribution having the recipient's address on the right.

Use `\LoadLetterOption{SN}` (Swiss letters with address field on the right side) in the preambel to get:

[image]

Or `\LoadLetterOption{NF}` (French letters):

[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused, the Q was in the list of questions with zero answers.Your answer is from january and much better than mine, why did i overlook it?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am sorry you did not have a chance to see it ;-)  The question was a bit unclear and I thought my answer was out of interest.

Comment: For a few hours now i can see deleted answers, it was too early. Your question is very very good, better than mine. But i like the busy bee ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is my best guess. Many many more information can be found in the answer by @esdd.

[image: renatoScrlttr2]

```
\documentclass[backaddress=false,fromalign=right,NF]{scrlttr2}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{-2cm}
\@setplength{toaddrwidth}{5cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Renato P.}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Lillipond lane\\Magnolia Town}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Bella Bee\\Honeycomb 42\\The hive}
    \opening{My Dear Bella,}
    it is a long time we haven't met and i miss you.
    \blindtext
    \closing{Wish You Were Here}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to shorten the `toaddrwidth` additionally? If the text in a line of the address field is longer it could run out of the paper without a warning. Use `\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}` in the preamble to show the position and the width of the address field.